# Url Parameter after logout Php?

Tags: php, ajax, url

After logout on my Page my Url contains the old Parameters like here the parameter to include dynamic the page but when i now login again i will redirect to the logout Page again and get logged out.

*Logout Page Reload*

```
     echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; url="./index.php">';
```

*Login Page Reoad after Login*

```
    location.reload();
```

*Parameter Url*

```
    /index.php?act=logout
```

S0 my Question... how to fix that is after logout no parameters at Url so that at least i get when i logout only /index.php ?

Comment: and the question is? problem?

Comment: what will happen if someone has javascript turned off?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Question is how to fix it ?

Comment: @SuperDJ not possible. Its a bigger Page wich is using Ajax requests and all ...so it doesnt matter xD

Comment: @MaddyS. how to fix what? you dropped code with no indication as to what is working or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cause Ajax users will know this problem ?

Comment: @MaddyS. ofcourse it is possible for users to turn off javascript. But the user is unable to logout when a user has no javascript?

Comment: I guess I didn't feel that 747 fly by me.

Comment: *It wasn't low enough Ralph.* The question makes no sense to me and I know a fair bit about AJAX @Fred-ii-

Comment: *WhooOOooosh* - That was the drift I "got" from you Sam @JayBlanchard meaning... I completely felt that one ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well seriously question doesn't make sense but ..
i don't know how your code is working but you can simple match in index.php

```
if($_GET['act'] == "logout"){
    //update parameter url parameter
}
```